# Create a Java 8 stream from a nullable list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there a way to check the null in java8, if list is null return null, else do the operations.

```
 public Builder withColors(List<String> colors) {
        this.colors= colors== null ? null :
                colors.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(color-> Color.valueOf(color))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return this;
    }
```

I see there is an option to use

```
Optional.ofNullable(list).map(List::stream)
```

but in this way I get error code on Color.valueOf(color)

Thanks

Comment: The answer is in the question, isn't it? The ternary operator is perfectly valid Java 8 code and there's no reason not to use it (other than using null lists, which is a bad idea in general: just use a never null, empty list).

Comment: What is the error you get? Can the List contain null values, or can only the List itself be null?
Assuming you use javafx.scene.paint.Color, the only error can origin from invalid color strings.

Comment: Don't use `Optional` for logic within a method. What is wrong with a simple null-check?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel simple null checks can be forgotten.That may sound like a lame excuse, but only until it takes down prod.
`Optional` is a replacement for null, you can and should use it anywhere. The idea behind it is that you always need to make a conscious decision between `get`, `orElse` and `orElseThrow` ensuring that you never forget to handle errors. I've been using Optional's heavy since they came out. I think the last time I made a NullPointerException was about a year ago

Comment: @sirolf2009 Optionals can be the right thing for return values, but when using them only to avoid null-checks like here they are code smell. Explicitly using optional just to avoid a null-check is not better (because you still have to think about using it), and adds overhead because you are instantiating additional objects. If limited within a single method, a null-check is cheaper and likely more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Optional.ofNullable(list).map(List::stream)` would give you a `Optional<Stream<String>>`, which you can't call `filter` on.

You can put the entire `Stream` processing inside the `Optional`'s `map()`:

```
public Builder withColors(List<String> colors) {
    this.colors = Optional.ofNullable(colors).map(
        list -> list.stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map(color-> Color.valueOf(color))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .orElse(null);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: You can call `filter` on an `Optional<Stream<String>>`, but it would do something different.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things that may be you should re-think.

First of all may be passing a `Set<String> colors` instead of a `List` would make more sense, since it seems that `Color` is an enum to begin with. Then, may be it would make more sense to check against `equalsIgnoreCase`, so that `red` or `RED` would still produce an enum instance. Also an `if statement` is probably much more clear to check for a possibly null input. And last streaming in the opposite direction - from the `enum` would make more sense (also avoiding the null check) I have not implemented the recommendations above, just for simplicity.

```
public Builder withColors(List<String> colors) {
    if(colors == null){
        this.colors = Collection.emptyList();
    }

    this.colors = EnumSet.allOf(Color.class)
            .stream()
            .filter(x -> colors.stream().anyMatch(y -> x.toString().equals(y)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return this;
}
```